# I want to pull specific data from a text file

Tags: linux, text-processing, search

I have a file called `MemoryReport.txt` .

Somewhere in the middle of each line, it says `Limit:`.

I would like for a script to copy only lines that says `Limit:1` and exclude all others and print to a output text called `LowLimit.txt`

Comment: Should that include lines that contain e.g. `Limit:10` or `MaxLimit:1`? (`Limit:1` is a substring)

Comment: This should include Limit:1* so any number following 1 should also be captured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to do it, I figured it out.

```
grep "Limit:1" MemoryReport.txt > LowLimit.txt
```